# Listing SRC_URI of all packages/files needed to build Yocto image

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I would like to list all files that bitbake will fetch when I bake an image.

Currently, I am able to get the SRC_URI of all files needed to bake a Yocto image by executing `bitbake core-image-minimal -c fetchall` and then parse log files.

Is there is a simpler way to get the same result without the need to download files ?

I am not sure bitbake supports such feature. Ideally, I am looking for a command that prints out the package name and lists all files with corresponding URL

```
> bitbake core-image-minimal -c fetchall --print-only
```

Comment: There is a similar question listed on SuperUser https://superuser.com/questions/977100/yocto-bitbake-list-of-files-which-are-to-download-in-the-build-process It has no answers at present but if a good one is found here it may be appropriate there too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generally *bitbake* doesn't provides such functionality.

But I was able to create a simple solution witch creating simple *.bbclass* file which is inherited in all recipes, by adding it into *local.conf* file, please see my steps in order to archive that:

Steps:

1. let's create a class **print-src.bbclass** file used to get and print **SRC_URI** variable (remember to store this class file in layer which is available in conf/bblayers.conf):

   ```
   $ cat print-src.bbclass

   python do_print_src () {
       # should probably be indented
       srcuri = d.getVar('SRC_URI', True).split()
       bb.warn("SRC_URI look like: %s" % srcuri)
   }

   addtask do_print_src before do_fetch
   ```
2. Add **INHERIT += "print-src"** into Your **conf/local.conf** file

**Edit:** it is important to use *bitbake --runonly* option, that allows to run specific task of the taskgraph for the specified target (with *--runonly* option *do_print_src* needs to be used as *print_src*),

**Edit:** Please note that *--runall=RUNALL* and *--runonly=RUNONLY* was introduced with [Yocto Sumo release 2.5](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.5/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#usage-and-syntax),

```
$ bitbake core-image-minimal --runonly print_src
Loaded 1236 entries from dependency cache.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.37.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal-4.8"
TARGET_SYS           = "i586-poky-linux"
MACHINE              = "qemux86"
DISTRO               = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "2.5"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "m32 i586"
TARGET_FPU           = ""
meta                 
meta-poky            
meta-yocto-bsp       = "master:13cc30cd7de4841990b600e83e1249c81a5171dd"

Initialising tasks: 100% |##########################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
WARNING: ptest-runner-2.2+gitAUTOINC+49956f65bb-r0 do_print_src: SRC_URI look like: ['git://git.yoctoproject.org/ptest-runner2']
WARNING: grep-3.1-r0 do_print_src: SRC_URI look like: ['http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/grep/grep-3.1.tar.xz', 'file://0001-Unset-need_charset_alias-when-building-for-musl.patch']
...
... 
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 201 tasks of which 0 didn't need to be rerun and all succeeded.

Summary: There were 202 WARNING messages shown.
```

Please see sample warning output log line:

**WARNING:** ptest-runner-2.2+gitAUTOINC+49956f65bb-r0 do_print_src: SRC_URI look like: ['git://git.yoctoproject.org/ptest-runner2'].

Comment: Very interesting solution, but I am not getting SRC_URI of all packages needed to build an image. Any idea ?

Comment: I am not sure for 100%, but it look like some tasks are cached. Are You able to rm tmp/ ssache/ and cache dirs, then I think class should prints SRC_URI in all depends recipes.

Comment: Yes, I tried `bitbake my-image -c do_print_src` on a clean workspace

Comment: You are right, for recipes without SRC_URI (like *core-image-minimal*) this solution is just run single one target and finish - currently I don't know how to _force_ bitbake to run all dependency chain tasks. I with to try correct this. But please try use *world* target _$ bitbake world -c do_print_src_ which is actually prints SRC_URI's for each recipes.

Comment: @Bechir I am was able to solve problem with no outputs while recipe without SRC_URI is used. Please take look at my edited post.

Comment: With *pyro* version, I am got an error `bitbake: error: no such option: --runonly`. Used `--runall=print_src` instead. Worked for me. (y)

Comment: nonetheless,  I still think that such feature should be built-in !

Comment: @Bechir, I noticed that actually *--runall=RUNALL* and *--runonly=RUNONLY* was introduced in latest release (2.5 Yocto Sumo)[https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.5/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#usage-and-syntax]

Comment: With nostamp feature we could avoid the cache depedency. do_print_src[nostamp] = "1"

Answer (score 2):

I patched poky to create `*.src` files in `downloads` that contains the effective fetch URL of the package.

```
 bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/__init__.py | 19 ++++++++++++++-----
 1 file changed, 14 insertions(+), 5 deletions(-)

diff --git a/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/__init__.py b/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/__init__.py
index b853da30bd..03e84e0919 100644
--- a/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/__init__.py
+++ b/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/__init__.py
@@ -1257,16 +1257,16 @@ class FetchData(object):

         # Note: .done and .lock files should always be in DL_DIR whereas localpath may not be.
         if self.localpath and self.localpath.startswith(dldir):
-            basepath = self.localpath
+            self.basepath = self.localpath
         elif self.localpath:
-            basepath = dldir + os.sep + os.path.basename(self.localpath)
+            self.basepath = dldir + os.sep + os.path.basename(self.localpath)
         elif self.basepath or self.basename:
-            basepath = dldir + os.sep + (self.basepath or self.basename)
+            self.basepath = dldir + os.sep + (self.basepath or self.basename)
         else:
              bb.fatal("Can't determine lock path for url %s" % url)

-        self.donestamp = basepath + '.done'
-        self.lockfile = basepath + '.lock'
+        self.donestamp = self.basepath + '.done'
+        self.lockfile = self.basepath + '.lock'

     def setup_revisions(self, d):
         self.revisions = {}
@@ -1607,6 +1607,15 @@ class Fetch(object):
             m = ud.method
             localpath = ""

+            p = "%s.src"%ud.basepath
+            d = os.path.dirname(p)
+            if d != '':
+                bb.utils.mkdirhier(d)
+            with open(p, 'wb') as f:
+                data = "%s" % ud.url
+                f.write(bytes(data, 'ASCII'))
+            return True
+
             if ud.lockfile:
                 lf = bb.utils.lockfile(ud.lockfile)
```

Running `bitbake core-image-minimal -c fetchall` results:

```
$> find downloads/ -name '*.src' | head -n 5
downloads/lzop-1.03.tar.gz.src
downloads/libtheora-1.1.1.tar.bz2.src
downloads/mpfr-3.1.5.tar.xz.src
downloads/makedevs.c.src
downloads/expat-2.2.0.tar.bz2.src
```

This is not an optimal solution but I hope that such feature gets its way to mainline stream.

Answer (score 1):

I needed something like this and got part way there before now.

I can generate a messy list of URIs used by executing the following command:

```
bitbake -g zlib && cat recipe-depends.dot | \
grep -v -e '-native' | grep -v digraph | \
grep -v -e '-image' | awk '{print $1}' | \
sort | uniq | xargs -I {} -t bitbake -e {} | grep SRC_URI=
```

This gives you all the URIs and files used in a recipe and some comments.

Not a perfect solution but I will see if I can improve on it.

Answer (score 1):

A bit manual and straight forward way is to build your image from scratch, and copy all the fetch logs, and go thru it.

```
$ mkdir fetch_logs
$ find tmp/work/ -type f -name log.do_fetch*  | cpio -pdm fetch_logs
```

Now grep "Fetch(ing/er)" in this fetch_logs and it will provide info on which URL your recipe used to fetch the source. This will be helpful to see the final URI used to fetch in PREMIRROR based builds.

NOTE: if you have sstate-cache enabled and functional, you may not see do_fetch at all.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote scripts based on the solution in the question.
Basically I need to make a cscope project of all the sources, and hence I need to list all URI and clone all repos.
I wrote 2 scripts 1) List all SRC_URI and Branches
                  2) Install(clone) all the code in a single directory

**listURI.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
TMP_FILE="___x__2242230p.txt"
SRCH_FILE="log.do_fetch"
TIME=$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M)
OUT_FILE="Project-$TIME.txt"
DEF_BRANCH="master"
BRANCH=""
SRC_URI=""

function usage {
    echo "Usage : $0 < -f | -g > <Component-List-file>"
    echo "Options :"
    echo "        -f    : Run bitbake fetch and collect URI"
    echo "        -g    : Get URI from Already fetched Project"
}

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    usage
    exit
fi

if [ "$1" == "-f" ] || [ "$1" == "-g" ];then
    if [ "$1" == "-f" ] && [  -z "$2" ];then
        echo "Should pass Project-Name after -f Option"
        exit
    fi
else
    echo "Unknown Option"
    usage
    exit
fi
POKYROOTDIR=`basename "$PWD"`
#echo $POKYROOTDIR
if [[ $POKYROOTDIR != "build" ]];then
    echo "You are not on poky/build (Sourced Poky) Directory"
    exit 0
fi
POKYROOTDIR=$PWD

if [ "$1" == "-f" ];then
    echo "Running === bitbake -c fetchall $2 -f --no-setscene =="
     bitbake -c fetchall $2 -f --no-setscene
fi

if [ "$1" == "-g" ];then
    if [ ! -d tmp/work ];then
        echo " Please run == bitbake -c fetchall <image> -f --no-setscene == before this"
        usage
        exit
    fi
fi

echo "Looking for URIs --- It may take couple of minuites!"

rm -rf $OUT_FILE
cd tmp/work
find . -name $SRCH_FILE -exec grep -i 'DEBUG: For url git' {} \; -print > $POKYROOTDIR/$TMP_FILE
cd $POKYROOTDIR

while IFS= read -r line
do
      #echo "$line"
      BRANCH=$(echo $line | awk -F"branch=" '/branch=/{print $2}' | sed -e 's/;/ /' | awk '{print $1}')
      SRC_URI=$(echo $line | cut -d';' -f1-1 | awk -F"url" '/url/{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}' | sed -e 's/git:/ssh:/')

      if [ ! -z "$BRANCH" ] && [ ! -z "$SRC_URI" ];then
          echo "$BRANCH  $SRC_URI" >> $OUT_FILE
      elif [ ! -z "$SRC_URI" ];then
          echo "$DEF_BRANCH  $SRC_URI" >> $OUT_FILE
      fi

    if [ ! -z "$BRANCH" ];then
      echo "Found URI : BRANCH:$BRANCH URI:$SRC_URI"
    elif [ ! -z "$SRC_URI" ];then
        echo "Found URI : BRANCH:Default URI:$SRC_URI"
    fi
      #echo "$BRANCH  $SRC_URI" >> $OUT_FILE
done < "$TMP_FILE"

#echo "=================== OUT PUT ==========================="
#cat $OUT_FILE

rm -rf $TMP_FILE


echo "----------------INFO-----------------"
echo "Project Creation: Success"
echo "Project Path      : $POKYROOTDIR"
echo "Project file      : $OUT_FILE"

echo "-------------------------------------"
```

**installURI.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

function usage {
    echo "Usage : $0 <List-file>"
}

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    usage
    exit
fi

if [ -z "$1" ];then
    usage
    exit
fi


if [ ! -z "$(ls -A $PWD)" ]; then
    echo "Directory ($PWD) must be Empty.... else it will mess up project creation"
    exit
fi

if [ ! -f $1 ];then
    echo "list file ($1) not found"
    usage
    exit
fi

filename=$1
while read -r line; do
    name="$line"
    echo "Fetching Projects"
    git clone -b $line
done < "$filename"

echo "----------------INFO-----------------"
echo "Project Creation: Success"
echo "Project Path    : $PWD"
echo "-------------------------------------"
```